# Help on apex TestClass?

Tags: apex

i need to cover the code coverage for trigger which contains Test.isRunningtest condition(IF condition), How to cover the code coverage for this condition?

Comment: It's impossible to have unit testing cover lines of code that never run during a test.

Comment: Check with the author of the trigger why the `if` is there: it would normally only be added where some code can't be run in a test (i.e. the code always fails when run from a test). If the check is there for a valid reason then just accept it can't be covered.

Answer (score 2):

> isRunningTest()  - Returns true if the currently executing code was
>   called by code contained in a test method, false otherwise. Use this
>   method if you need to run different code depending on whether it was
>   being called from a test.

isRunningTest() will always return true if you are running a test. Hence, all the code within your if(!isRunningTest()) bracket is not going to run if you are running a test, ever. If you want to cover this code at all, you are going to have to modify the code to remove the if(!isRunningTest()) condition.

You can check the references [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm)